# What is the difference bewteen Mapper.Map(source, dest) and Mapper.Map(source)?

Tags: c#, automapper

I can see the difference in the number of parameters, but I don't know the difference in implementation.

Is there an important difference in the behavior of each method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one fills an existing object that you pass in.  The second creates a new object for you.  It's the semantic difference between "Project" and "Fill".